# Oracle 11g Regular expression Multiple Instances of Pattern

Tags: regex, oracle

I need to extract the information from '< a href="...">something.jpg< /a>' tags from a large string recursively that could contain multiple instances of the tags. I need to do this using regex on Oracle 11g.

An example of what I am looking for is:

Example String:

The string will always contain at least 1 instance of the < a> tag and there is no maximum to how many it can contain
The href will always a xid-[[:digit:]]
The attributes in the tag can vary

```
<p>text about something important</p><p><a href="@X@EmbeddedFile.requestUrlStub@X@bbcswebdav/xid-1234_1" target="_blank">file.pdf</a> </p><p><a href="@X@EmbeddedFile.requestUrlStub@X@bbcswebdav/xid-1235_1" target="_blank">anotherfile.pptx</a> </p><p><a href="@X@EmbeddedFile.requestUrlStub@X@bbcswebdav/xid-1236_1" target="_blank">yetanotherfile.pdf</a> </p>
```

Now with that string I want to extract the 3 < a ...>...< /a> blocks using
 
REGEXP_SUBSTR(< string>, '< pattern>', < start>, < occurrence >) and adjusting the occurrence value to grab the 3 instances.

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(main_data, ''<a[[:print:]]+href="[[:print:]]+xid-1234_1"[[:print:]]+>[[:print:]]+</a>'', 1, 1)
      FROM table
```

and the results I get from that are

```
<a href="@X@EmbeddedFile.requestUrlStub@X@bbcswebdav/xid-1234_1" target="_blank">file.pdf</a> </p><p><a href="@X@EmbeddedFile.requestUrlStub@X@bbcswebdav/xid-1235_1" target="_blank">anotherfile.pptx</a> </p><p><a href="@X@EmbeddedFile.requestUrlStub@X@bbcswebdav/xid-1236_1" target="_blank">yetanotherfile.pdf</a>
```

So it is starting with the first < a and then grabbing all the way to the last < /a>. When I need it to stop at the first instance of < /a>. Then when I increment the occurrence to 2 it should grab the second set of < a>< /a> tags. However currently setting the occurrence to 2 nothing is returned.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the non-greedy operator `?` is the solution:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(x,'<a href="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)</a>',1, 3, 'i', 0)
  FROM (SELECT '<p>text about something important</p><p><a href="@X@EmbeddedFile.requestUrlStub@X@bbcswebdav/xid-1234_1" target="_blank">file.pdf</a> </p><p><a href="@X@EmbeddedFile.requestUrlStub@X@bbcswebdav/xid-1235_1" target="_blank">anotherfile.pptx</a> </p><p><a href="@X@EmbeddedFile.requestUrlStub@X@bbcswebdav/xid-1236_1" target="_blank">yetanotherfile.pdf</a> </p>' as x FROM DUAL);
```

returns

```
<a href="@X@EmbeddedFile.requestUrlStub@X@bbcswebdav/xid-1236_1" target="_blank">yetanotherfile.pdf</a>
```

or the other tags if you change the `3` to 1 or 2.

If you replace the last `0` with `1`, you get the contents of the href:

```
@X@EmbeddedFile.requestUrlStub@X@bbcswebdav/xid-1236_1
```

If you replace it with `2`, you get

```
yetanotherfile.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Oracle's various XML facilities instead?

For example, place the text into a CLOB and then use xmltype() and extract() to get the elements out using an XPath query ([see for example this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884421/oracle-10g-extract-data-select-from-xml-clob-type)).

Generally, trying to extracted nested data structures using regexes leads to unhappiness.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jacques Chester noted, it will be less painful if you can use the XML support.

If you cannot, try changing the `+` to `+?` to perform a non-greedy match.

The `+?` qualifier is part of the [Perl-influenced Extensions in Oracle Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/ap_posix003.htm)